# Find long and lat in a text file within a zone?

Tags: r

I have a text file contains information as follows:

```
     Grid Point Index, Latitude, Longitude, Cell
      167,    0.000000,    9.432301, 1350
      169,    0.000000,    9.544590, 1350
      171,    0.000000,    9.656878, 1350
      173,    0.000000,    9.769168, 1350
      175,    0.000000,    9.881457, 1350
      177,    0.000000,    9.993747, 1350
      179,    0.000000,   10.106036, 1386
      181,    0.000000,   10.218326, 1386
```

I would like to find all lat and long which belong to this zone

```
     :lat 40.000  ,43.00 and long 0.000000, 3.902665.
```

well, I can do it manually but this will take lots of the time. Can anybody help me to build this function

```
              insert the zone of lat and long
```

then will find the all lat-long within this zone in the file and the corresponding grid point index and cell.

to read the file

```
              das= read.table("C:\\Users\\lonlatnter.txt", sep=",",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: 1. What do you have so far? 2. Your description is not clear. You want points inside the zone or the points closest to the zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo <- function(df,  latMin, latMax, longMin, longMax) {
    return (
        df[
            df$Latitude >= latMin & df$Latitude <= latMax &
            df$Longitude >= longMin & df$Longitude <= longMax,
            c('Grid.Point.Index', 'Cell')
        ]
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
> foo(das, latMin=40, latMax=43, longMin=0, longMax=3.902665)
[1] Grid.Point.Index Cell            
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

> das[1,c(2,3)] <- c(41.0, 2)

> foo(das, latMin=40, latMax=43, longMin=0, longMax=3.902665)
Grid.Point.Index Cell
1            167 1350
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this data.frame X that contains your data. You can select rows by writing the condition into the index brackets:

```
X[ cond1 & cond2 & ..., ]
```

In your example:

```
a <- 40
b <- 43
c <- 0
d <- 3.9
X[ X$Lat > a & x$Lat < b & X$Lon > c & X$Lon < d, ]
```

Comment: btw: you're sure you want to work with coordinate's zones and not distances?